# Как убрать анимацию изменения statusbar когда я меняю его прозрачность?

Tags: android

Есть `Activity`. В `Activity` есть `WelcomeFragment`, с прозрачным `StatusBar`.
Прозрачным его делаю в `onCreateView` фрагмента:

```
getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

В `onCreateView` следующего фрагмента делаю:

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().show();
getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

Но из-за анимации изменения `status bar` разметка отображается некорректно. 
Как убрать анимацию?